# R Programming: Using ISO Country Codes in LeafLet

Tags: r, shiny, rworldmap, leaflet.draw

I am working on creating a client dashboard. I have ISO country codes for the clients also I have plotted the same in the map using rworldmap package, but the UI is not very good.

So, I want to use the leaflet package. How can I use these ISO Country Codes ALPHA 2 in creating the map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet does not accept ISO Alpa2 code rather accepts ISO Alpha3 codes. After going through almost everywhere I tried this and it solved my problem.

```
output$myMapOne = renderPlotly({
       height  = 1000 
       units="px"
       clientName = input$clientSelector
       conWiseSub = subset(conData, conData$GCA_CSTMR_DS == clientName)
       defOne = aggregate(CNT ~ CODE, conWiseSub, sum)
       d = defOne$CODE
       e = defOne$CNT

       # light grey boundaries
       l <- list(color = toRGB("grey"), width = 0.5)

       # specify map projection/options
       g <- list(
         showframe = TRUE,
         showcoastlines = FALSE,showland = TRUE,showcountries = TRUE,
         countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
         landcolor = toRGB("grey85"),
         projection = list(type = 'Mercator', scale =1)
       )

       plot_ly(defOne, z = e, text = d,locations = d,  type = 'choropleth',
               color = e, colors = 'PuBu', marker = list(line = l), colorbar = list(title = "SOI Distribution")
              ) %>%
         layout( geo = g,title= paste("Region Wise SOI Distribution of", clientName , sep = " "))
     })
```

[Click Here to View the Map Created By the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc23j.png)

Hope this helps!!